# How to start constructing a logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, workflow, design-process

When designing something like the logo below, what is the right approach to start?

I face problems with angles. I can't determine the angle from the picture and  incorporate that into my design.

How do I determine/figure out the measurement of the angle of an existing or already-finished logo?

Should I decide the angle first then start constructing? Or without deciding anything, do I simply start constructing and do whatever the design demands?

Like the picture I have attached, I want to know the angle between two bars of the 'A', so that I can know which angle would be perfect to flip it in the opposite direction.

[image]

Comment: To the person responsible for the close vote: please stop voting to close beginner questions.  This question doesn't need more focus, it's perfectly obvious. The OP is clearly a beginner who doesn't know how to approach something like this.  Even the most experienced graphic designers had to learn stuff like this when starting out.

Comment: I have always found designs that incorporate the [golden angle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_angle) to be aesthetically pleasing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The example logo is made of simple geometric shapes - a circle, equilateral triangles, and rectangles.

Draw something like this: Here I have a circle, two equilateral triangles and a line - all have a thick stroke.

[image]

Convert the strokes to paths by doing *Object > Expand*

Draw an additional rectangle along the top of the shapes

[image]

Hold down <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> and click and drag with the Shape Builder tool to remove the pieces that are not required.

[image]

Open up the Pathfinder, and press the Unite button to unite all the pieces as one shape.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.i just realize my approaching was wrong.

Comment: @suraiyaabedin - there are no wrong approaches in Illustrator. You can do whatever you want to get the job done. There are many ways this could be done. This is just one method.

Comment: Thank you so much Billy Kerr for this comment. it means a lot.